# Uso de YUM para todos los usuarios

Tags: linux, centos, rhel

Instalo python con `yum` y solo me lo reconoce *root*.
Instalo django como *root* y solo me lo reconoce *root*.

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer extensivo a todos los usuarios?

Comment: ¿Te sale algún error? ¿Puedes mostrarnos cómo lo estás haciendo?

Comment: No pongas "resuelto" en tu pregunta: en su lugar, [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Answer (score 1):

Respondo a mi propia duda.

El problema no era en la instalación, sino que python3.9 crea por defecto la variable **python3** y no **python**